# Linq: find elements with common properties but different types

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list with objects:

```
class Class1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Guid UniqueIdentifier { get; set; }
    public bool IsValid { get; set; }
}

class Class2
{
    public int Identifier { get; set; }
    public string Producer{ get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public int SupplierId { get; set; }
}
```

Is there a way to use `linq` to get the elements of type `Class1` from the list that have the same `Id` (identifier) and `Guid` with the elements of type `Class2` from the second list?

Comment: You mean to get all elements from list1 that has a corresponding element from list2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
var result = list1
    .Where(x => list2.Any(y => x.Id == y.Identifier && x.UniqueIdentifier == y.Guid))
    .ToList();
```

Please note that this version is not optimized for large lists. If your lists are small, this is fine. If you have large lists, you need a solution that involves things like `HashSet`s. Here is an example:

```
var list2HashSet = CreateHashset(list2.Select(x => new {x.Identifier, x.Guid}));

var result = list1
    .Where(x => list2HashSet.Contains(new {Identifier = x.Id, Guid = x.UniqueIdentifier}))
    .ToList();
```

Where `CreateHashset` is defined like this:

```
public static HashSet<T> CreateHashset<T>(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    return new HashSet<T>(collection);
}
```

I had to create this simple method because the compiler is complaining that it cannot resolve the correct constructor overload. I am not really sure why.

Comment: My lists would have around 500 k elements, so you would suggest to work with hashsets?

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
var result = from item1 in list1
             join item2 in list2 on 
                    new { G = item1.UniqueIdentifier, Id = item1.Id }  
             equals new { G = item2.Guid, Id = item2.Identifier }
             select new { item1, item2 };

foreach(var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Producer: {item.item2.Producer} with product: {item.item1.Name}");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have the two lists

```
List<Class1> List1;
List<Class2> List2;
```

You can select all items of List1 containing the Id and Guid of the second list with

```
List1.Where(C1 => List2.Any(C2 => C1.Id == C2.Identifier && C1.UniqueIdentifier == C2.Guid));
```

Note that `Guid` is a class. If you don't want to check if `C1.UniqueIdentifier` and `C2.Guid` are exactly the same objects, you should [implement IsEqual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/336aedhh(v=vs.100).aspx) and use it like

```
List1.Where(C1 => List2.Any(C2 => C1.Id == C2.Identifier && C1.UniqueIdentifier.Equals(C2.Guid)));
```

Answer (score 0):

If it suffice for you that the ids or the guids match, see the answer from Jeroen van Langen. Otherwise, I see two options:

1. Add a `where` clause afterwards, i.e.,

   var result = from item1 in list1
                join item2 in list2 on item1.Id equals item2.Identifier
                where item1.UniqueIdentifier = item2.Guid
                select new { item1, item2 };
2. Create a tuple class and join on the tuples of Guid and Id. You cannot reuse the .NET 4 tuple types (`Tuple<,>`), but you could reuse the C# 7 tuple types as they correctly implement equality.

Both versions should also be fine with large lists. Basically, the whole thing should scale as long as you use `join`.